# Setting LocalStorage Location via setOfflineStoragePath

Tags: qt, sqlite, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I'm trying to set the `LocalStorage` location (sqlite db) for my QML application but once i rebuild and run the application i still can't see the subfolder, INI file and the sqlite DB created on the desired location (in a subfolder within the resources folder). Here is what's in my **main** file.
Appreciate any one could pint what's I'm doing wrong here?

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDir>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    //engine.setOfflineStoragePath("qrc:/");
    auto offlineStoragePath = QUrl::fromLocalFile(engine.offlineStoragePath());
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("offlineStoragePath", offlineStoragePath);

    QString customPath = "qrc:/OffLineStorage";

    QDir dir;
    if(dir.mkpath(QString(customPath))){
        qDebug() << "Default path >> "+engine.offlineStoragePath();
        engine.setOfflineStoragePath(QString(customPath));
        qDebug() << "New path >> "+engine.offlineStoragePath();
    }


    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Did you check if `mkpath` actually creates the required path? I mean, it could simply be that the body of the `if` statement is never executed.

Comment: @skypjack just checked skypjack, folder is not created. I will manually create it and give it ago. Thanks looking in to this.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm adding the comment as a response in a few minutes, in order to accept it and close the question if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the code snippet in your question, everything looks fine.
Anyway, you should verify if the following line actually returns `true` as you expect:

```
dir.mkpath(QString(customPath)
```

If no, the body of the `if` statement isn't executed in any case, thus `setOfflineStoragePath` is never invoked.
As a hint, using `qrc:/OffLineStorage` as a path for your storage doesn't seem to be a good idea. I'm not sure it will work once in the production environment (to be checked, it sounds strange, but it could work).

Comment: Tried creating the folder manually and running but still no luck . I think its restricted by design. Reverting back to using the default location :)

Thank you got looking at this.

Comment: I usually use the default location, but once I've also given the user the chance to choose the desired location. Anyway, the default location is somehow a good choice for most of the cases. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try use `engine.setOfflineStoragePath` before `engine.load`.

> Using qrc:/OffLineStorage as a path for your storage doesn't seem to
>   be a good idea. I'm not sure it will work once in the production
>   environment

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDir>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    QString customPath = "qrc:/OffLineStorage";  
    QDir dir;
    if(dir.mkpath(QString(customPath))){
        qDebug() << "Default path >> "+engine.offlineStoragePath();
        engine.setOfflineStoragePath(QString(customPath));
        qDebug() << "New path >> "+engine.offlineStoragePath();
    }

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    engine.clearComponentCache();
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```